# datepicker beforeShowDay vs. selected

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker that has a special highlight using beforeShowDay. However, the highlight style prevents the selected ("ui-btn-active") style, which is automatically applied when a cell is clicked. What is the best approach to get the selected style on top?

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>

.Highlighted a{
background: none !important;
background-color: #990066 !important;
}

        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                return [true, SelectedDates[date] ? 'Highlighted' : ''];
            }
        });
```

Adding this has no effect:

```
.Highlighted ui-btn-active a{
background: none !important;
background-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: put a fiddle of your datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var selected = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
                if (date.getDate() != selected.getDate()) return [true, SelectedDates[date] ? 'Highlighted' : ''];
                else return [true, '']
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your beforeShowDay code add the ui-btn-active class to the selected elements after adding them Highlighted class.

Remember elements can have multiple classes.

Comment: I can not, as the style "Highlighted" is returned, not set in the function.

Comment: Try this: return [true, SelectedDates[date] ? 'Highlighted ui-btn-active' : ''];

Comment: I only want it to have the class ui-btn-active when it is clicked, which it automatically does for cells that do not have Highlighted.

Comment: Then onClick event of any of datepicker days add it the class